# Laravel 8, whereRelation take the where value condition from model

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

i'm using whereRelation but i do not know
how to take the where value condition from the base model

I have tried this code:

```
Item::with('unit','stock')->whereRelation('stock', 'stock', '<', 'items.min_stock');
```

and query result in debugger :

```
select * from `items` where exists (select * from `stocks` where `items`.`id` = `stocks`.`id_item` and `stock` < 'items.min_stock')
```

The query result i wanted :

```
select * from `items` where exists (select * from `stocks` where `items`.`id` = `stocks`.`id_item` and `stock` < `items`.`min_stock`)
```

**'items.min_stock'** it become like a string, How can i solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution for my code

i change my code like this and it's works

```
Item::with('unit','stock')->whereRelation('stock', 'stock', '<', DB::raw('items.min_stock'));
```

thanks to @Vildan Bina for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try using `whereRaw`

```
Item::with('unit','stock')->whereRelation('stock', function (Builder $query) {
    $query->whereRaw('stock < items.min_stock'); // semicolon
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Otherize you can use `whereHas` method, example below:

```
 Item::with('unit', 'stock')->whereHas('stock', function ($query) {
            $query->where('stock', '<', DB::raw('items.min_stock'))
        });
```